# Error while installing Face_recognition Library

Tags: python

I was installing Face_recognition library in python but somehow getting error while it installs the Dlib….

[image]

[[image][[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC7x6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install cmake:

pip install cmake

Answer (score 0):

Like it says at the bottom of the second screenshot, try installing CMake first.